# Как связать фильтр в запросе со значениями столбца?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

В клиентской программе в необходимом разделе есть фильтр по месяцу, значения присваивает весьма просто: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 12.

Столкнулся с проблемой: в БД есть таблица, в которой есть столбцы, названные месяцами, с необходимыми мне данными.
Однако, названы они не по аналогии с фильтром: 1...12, а
day_jan, day_feb, day_mar, day_apr и т.д.

Каким красивым способом можно связать фильтр в клиенте с данными столбцами, чтобы 1 в фильтре соответствовало столбцу `day_jan` таблицы и т.д.?

Собственно, сам селект:

```
select count(:g_mounth) as one
from   metrology.graf_lines t
join   metrology.graf_shapka gs 
on     gs.id = t.graf_id
join   metrology.equipment_type et 
on     et.id = t.equipment_type_id
join   metrology.v_user_permission_view v 
on     v.dep_id = t.department_id
and    v.mt_id = et.dic_measure_type_id
where  t.control_executer_id <> 24 
and    :g_mounth = '* ' 
and    t.dic_purpose_id = 3 
and    et.buro_id = :buro_id
and    gs.pyear = :year
and    t.dic_control_type_id = 1
```

Переменная `:g_mounth` отвечает за значение переменной из фильтра.
Думал, значения в фильтре сменить с цифр на названия столбцов - т.е. напрямую в переменную класть `"day_jan"` и т.д., но тогда при обращение к базе значение переменной (т.к. строка) берется в кавычки, и в итоге работает, но совсем неправильно.

Comment: Боюсь придется вопреки нормальной практике (10 раз убедившись что в поле не могут попасть неожиданные значения) подставлять значение непосредственно в текст запроса, а не через привязываемые переменные. Либо использовать жуткий `decode(:g_mounth,1,day_jan,2,day_feb,...)` Наиболее правильным решением было бы изменить структуру БД, нормализовать ее, переведя эти столбцы в отдельную таблицу где они были бы строками, например.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо! В принципе, декод дает приближенные к реальности результаты.

Answer (score 2):

Переменные связывания неприменимы к именам столбцов. Одно из решений - развернуть стобцы в записи функцией `UNPIVOT`, а затем фильтровать по значению переменной связывания:

```sql
var mon number
exec :mon := 3
with source (id, jan, feb, mar, apr) as (
    select 1, 11, 12, 13, 14 from dual union all 
    select 2, 21, 22, 23, 24 from dual 
),
target as (
    select *
    from source unpivot (val for mon in (jan as 1, feb as 2, mar as 3, apr as 4)) 
)
select *  
from target
where mon = :mon
/
```

Результат:

```
        ID        MON    VAL
---------- ---------- ------
         1          3     13
         2          3     23
```